# How to search the minimum n that 10^n ≡ 1 mod(9x) for given x

Tags: algorithm, performance, loops

For given `x`, I need to calculate the minimum `n` that equates true for the formula `10^n ≡ 1 (mod 9x)`

My algorithm is simple. For `i = 1 to inf`, I loop it until I get a result. There is always a result if `gcd(10, x) = 1`. Meanwhile if I don't get a result, I increase `i` by 1 .

This is really slow for big primes or numbers with a factorization of big values, so I ask if there is another way to calculate it faster. I have tried with threads, getting each thread the next `10^i` to calculate. Performance is a bit better, but big primes still don't finish.

Comment: You can avoid the GCD/modulus calculation on every iteration by calculating `10^(n+1) % 9x` in terms of `10^n % 9x`.

Comment: If you do the calculation mod 9x this should not be slow. Btw. what's the typical size of `x`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I avoid GCD because I never pass my algorithm a number with divisors 2 or 5.

Comment: @Henry my `x` is up to `2^31 - 1`. The slow speed of my algorithm is marked by the factorization of the `x`.

Comment: @Henry For example, the result for `x =  954661` is `456566`.

Comment: I don't get why you have to factor x.

Comment: @Henry Sorry I expressed bad. I mean that numbers with big values of its factorization are those for witch the algorithm works really bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the example, it runs in less than one second:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1;
        int x =  954661;
        int v = 10;
        while (v != 1) {
            n++;
            v = (v * 10) % (9*x);
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

For larger values of `x` the variables should be of type `long`.

Comment: Yes I got that result too. Try with `x = 58630544`

Comment: Sorry, for `x = 3664409 ( = 58630544 / 16)`

Comment: Note: I need to work with BigIntegers, because `v` overflows easily 2^31, and also 2^63 in case of a `long`.

Comment: `x = 3664409` gives the result 1570458, also in less than a second. As long as x is in integer range you should be able to work with longs. No need to go to `BigInteger`.

Comment: How did you manage that? I mean I use `BigInteger` for the `v`. For example, in this case you say that `v` would be `10^1570458`. Well, I have just seen that module operation is used in each iteration. Ok! I'm going to try.

Comment: Using the chinese remainder theorem you can also simply work `mod x` since 10^n % 9 is 1 for all n.

Comment: I think I only can work `mod x` when `3 not divides x`

Comment: Well that optimization really worked! I didn't realize about it. I have tried and there are still some numbers with wich algorithm works really slow, for example, `x = 64094679`;

Comment: Sure? I get the answer 956340 rather fast (using long for v and n). Btw. you are right about working mod x.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Assuming your `x` is relatively prime with 10, the following holds:

```
10 ^ φ(9x) ≡ 1 (mod 9x)
```

Here φ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). So you can easily calculate at least one `n` (not necessarily the smallest) for which your equation holds. To find the smallest such `n`, just iterate through the list of `n`'s divisors.

---

Example: x = 89 (a prime number just for simplicity).

```
9x = 801
φ(9x) = 6 * (89 - 1) = 528 (easy to calculate for a prime number)
```

The list of divisors of 528:

```
1
2
3
4
6
8
11
12
16
22
24
33
44
48
66
88
132
176
264
528
```

Trying each one, you can find that your equation holds for 44:

```
10 ^ 44 ≡ 1 (mod 801)
```

Comment: In that case `44` I have proved that is the smallest `n`. But, as you have said, doesn't always your algorithm return the minimun `n`? I need the smallest :S

Comment: It's easy to prove

Comment: The smallest divisor that holds the equation is the smallest `n` desired?

Answer (score -3):

As you specified you are actually trying to get modulus with 1 that is `1mod(9x)`.
That will always give you 1.

And you don't have to calculate that part exactly which might reduce your calculation.

On the other hand for `10^n = 1`, it will always be 0.
So can you exactly specify what you are trying to do

Comment: It is clearly specified. Maybe you watch it better as `( (10^n) mod (9x) ) = 1`